# Can't Get Json from Flask Rest API using getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, json, flask

I am new in Javascript and I get the following problem. So I make a simple Flask API return a simple json

Flask code:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/test')
def test():
    return jsonify({"result":"wt is works!"})

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run()
```

I run it using `gunicorn -k gevent -w 5 main:app` and when I check `localhost:8000/test` in browser it returns the json normally

But when I try to get it using Jquery it return nothing. My HTML didn't get any value from `localhost:8000/test`

My current html code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type=text/javascript>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $.getJSON(
                    "http://localhost:8000/test",
                    {format: "json"})
                    .done(
                        function(data) {
                            var plot_id = data.result;
                            $("#retval").html( "<strong>" + plot_id + "</strong>" );
                        }
                    );
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="retval"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

But when I change the url and try to get data from another API, let say from https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1 it works.

I've tried solution from:

- [Python Flask get json data to display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24735810/python-flask-get-json-data-to-display) (without `.done()` and using `.ajax`)
- [External API GET() request using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9984665/external-api-get-request-using-jquery) (using `callback=?`)
- And also tried to run using `python` command instead of `gunicorn`

but it still doesn't work, can somebody help me please to find out what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Define the port to be used as server port: `app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)`
- More important,the way browser get `localhost:8000/test` between your function `getJSON` or `ajax` are different. It has a problem about ***'access-control-allow-origin'***. In flask, you could use the package [flask-CORS](https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to get the job done.

Comment: wow, flask-CORS solved my problem :) I didn't know that until just now. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You have a few errors in your JS.

Most obviously, you are requesting an invalid URL. 0.0.0.0 is an interface you can bind your server to, but it is not a URL you can request. Use localhost or 192.168.0.1.

I would say thay the other main error is that there is no comma between the URL and the following options object, but in fact `getJSON` does not take an options parameter. Remove that object altogether.

Comment: oh sorry about the url, I've mixed my code. I've change it to localhost and put a comma. But It still doesn't work. And what should I remove? the  `format`? I've just tried to remove it and it still doesn't work

Comment: I've updated my code fixing the `localhost` and a comma

Comment: You need to do some debugging. Is the request being made to your Flask app at all? Can you see it either in the browser debugging tools or in the Flask console itself? If so, what is being returned?